# Notation: Why Ω for the based loop functor?

Tags: algebraic-topology, notation, category-theory, loop-spaces

This is just a question about notation - probably useless, but it's always baffled me:

Why was $\Omega$ chosen to denote the based loop functor? (e.g. for a pointed topological space $X$, $\Omega X$ is the space of based loops on $X$.)

I once heard someone speculate: "It's because $\Omega$ looks like... *a loop?* "

If true, clever choice! Can anyone verify and/or know more?

Comment: I think $O$ looks more like a loop, don't you?

Comment: @s.harp: Yes, but a Greek "Omicron" looks too much like a Latin "Oh".

Comment: I am pretty sure that Peter May will answer that question - if you post it on mathoverflow. :-)

Comment: @HeinrichD Ha, I was starting to wonder if mathoverflow would be a better fit - I'll post it there. Thanks for the nudge!